# In perl, how to make a variable holding the number zero print as "0" instead of ""

Tags: perl

I've been wondering about this one for years... In perl, the number 0 when stored in a variable is wronging translated into a string as "" when printed.  How to fix this problem?

For Example:

```
$X = 0;
print "X = $x\n";
```

One would expect this would print:
    X = 0

instead it prints:
    X =

Is there an easy way to make this print correctly without writing junky code like this:

```
$x = 0;
$xstr = !$x ?  "0" : $x;
print "X = $Xstr\n";
```

This is the one thing i really hate about perl when trying to write programs that perform math and print math results..

Perhaps there is some "use" package that i can add to my code to fix the printing of number zero as a string?

Comment: I am not sure I understand, the following expresssons `my $x = 0; print "\$x is $x\n";` prints 0 on my machine. How does `$x` get its value? If it is the result of some conditional it won't usually return `0` it will return `""`. e.g. `my $x = (2+2) == 3;`

Comment: Have you tried this code? It prints the zero. Are you using some ancient version of perl?

Comment: Perl is case senstitive. `$x` and `$X` are two completely different variables.

Comment: if you add a use strict; to that first example you'll see that you have $X (capital x) assigned to 0 and then you print $x (lower case x). THe use strict will show this error

Comment: *"In perl, the number 0 when stored in a variable is wronging translated into a string as "" when printed."* Wrong. This is simply not the case.

Comment: maybe i was using perl 4 at the time...

Comment: It seems that your hatred and years of wondering have been unnecessary. Perl doesn't do this -- either version 5 or version 4 -- and you have imagined a problem that doesn't exist

Comment: voting to reopen.  mistaking case sensitivity rules isn't a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 4):

You sure you got the case right? In the above you define `$X` but print `$x` instead. Perl is case sensitive.

```
$ perl -e 'print "X = $undefined\n"'
X =
```

Comment: was this a problem in perl 4 verses perl 5?

Comment: @user4875388 According to [*Data Type and Objects* section](http://www-cgi.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/Web/People/rgs/pl-data.html) of [this Perl 4 manual](http://www-cgi.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/perl-man) I'd think it was case sensitive as well.

Comment: @user4875388 no, this isn't a perl 4 vs perl 5 difference.  but perl 5 provides `use strict;` which you should always use and which gives an error when you use an  undeclared variable, which would have alerted you to the bad variable name